# AssertionError at /api/movies/ 'MovieViewSet' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Iam trying to access  http://localhost:8000/api/movies/. But, it showing like this ..AssertionError at /api/movies/ 'MovieViewSet' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method. I attached my code below

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator,MaxValueValidator


class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    description = models.TextField(max_length =300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Rating(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stars = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(5)])

    class Meta:
        unique_together =(("user","movie"),)
        index_together =(("user","movie"),)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Movie,Rating

class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('id','title','description')

class RatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ('id','stars','user','movie')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework import routers
from django.conf.urls import include
from .views import MovieViewSet,RatingViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('movies',MovieViewSet,basename='movies')
router.register('ratings',RatingViewSet,basename='ratings')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Movie,Rating
from .serializers import MovieSerializer,RatingSerializer

class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    query_set = Movie.objects.all()
 
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

class RatingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    query_set =  Rating.objects.all()
    serializer_class =  RatingSerializer
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory, you need to include a queryset attribute, not query_set

Answer (score 1):

You should use `queryset` in your `views.py`, not `query_set`